# readr::read_csv use cols_only with spliced list

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

I am able to read in a subset of columns defined in `cols_only` like so:

```
x <- read_csv(filePath, col_types=cols_only(colA=col_character())
x <- read_csv(filePath, col_types=cols_only(colA='c'))
```

Both work fine, but I tried to create a list to pass into `cols_only` and splice it, like I do in many Tidyverse functions, but this one generates an error.

```
cols <- list(colA='c')
x <- read_csv(filePath, col_types=cols_only(!!!cols))
```

I tried this also as a named vector `cols <- c(colA='c')` but I get the error `Error in !cols: invalid argument type`.

Is this a limitation of the function? I saw this GitHub issue https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/971 so was hoping this function could support this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the splicing is not working, use `do.call`

```
library(readr)
df1 <- read_csv(file.choose(), col_types = do.call(cols_only, cols))
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
cols1 <- list(`Service Charge`='c', `MONTHLY FEES` = 'c')
df1 <- read_csv(file.choose(), 
        col_types = do.call(cols_only, cols1))
```

-output

```
head(df1)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  `Service Charge`      `MONTHLY FEES`            
#  <chr>                 <chr>                     
#1 Customer Transfer Dr. INVESTMENT PURCHASE       
#2 Customer Transfer Dr. INVESTMENT PURCHASE       
#3 Miscellaneous Payment PAYPAL
```

Comment: Excellent, it works. Do you know why splicing doesn't work in this case? Curious about the implementation and what exactly is missing.

Comment: @Raesu I am not sure about the reason.  May be it is a bug or may be the readr package is included in the ambit of splicing .  I expect it to work although the splicing works in most other cases.